# Raphael, constantly rotating path

Tags: javascript, path, raphael, rotation

I have a path in Raphael, and I want it to constantly rotating by some point

I have writen this :

```
window.onload = function(){

var paper = Raphael(10, 150, 320, 200);
var path = paper.path('M50 40 L50 90');
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
circle.attr('fill', 'green');

drawWheel(path, circle);
}

function drawWheel(path, circle){

path.animate({rotation: '360 50 90'}, 10000);
circle.animate({rotation: '360 50 90'}, 10000)
timeout = setTimeout("drawWheel(path, circle);", 10000);

}
```

So when the page is load I am creating raphael path and circle and than I am passing it to method drawWheel, which is animating those objects

Than I want to call it again after 10 seconds, so that the user would see constantly rotating object,

first all is going good till the calling setTimeout

than I am getting an error in firebug "path is not defined"

Am I calling the setTimeout wrong or what ?

---

I have modified the script and I made path global variable so now the script (the simplest version) looks like this :

```
window.onload = function(){

    var paper = Raphael(10, 150, 320, 200);
    path = paper.path('M50 40 L50 90');
    drawWheel(path, circle);
}

function drawWheel(path){

    path.animate({rotation: '360 50 90'}, 10000);
    timeout = setTimeout("drawWheel(path);", 10000);
}
```

So now there is now error in firebug at all, but the path is rotating 360 degrees and stops.

Even the setTimeout is calling, but after one animation nothing more is happening

Any ideas pleas ?